# React Native HTMLView Space between Paragaphs

Tags: react-native

I currently use (tried some others) for an project HTMLView (https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview) but its adds to much space between every element.

I just basicly need to render two types of tags P and H3 from a string. I also tried in my style to set margin and padding to 0 - but it hasnt any effect.

Any code suggestions? Or an easy function to run through the item.teaser and replace every P and H3 to a TEXT-Element with a specific class?

```
      <HTMLView addLineBreaks={false} value={item.teaser} stylesheet={htmlStyles.teaser} />
```

[image: space between paragraph and next elements]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
value={"<div>"+item.teaser+"</div>"}
```

As seen here:
https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview/issues/202

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

This works `const regex = /<br|\n|\r\s*\\?>/g;` and then use replace data with regex

Example :

```
<HTMLView
    value={symptom.text.trim().replace(regex, '')}
    stylesheet={webViewStyle}
 />
```

Styles

```
const webViewStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  font: {
    color: '#7ab900',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue will be the data which your passing to value param in HTMLView. There might be multiple tags in between and which are wrapped with parent tag. This library expects valid HTML, which means everything should be wrapped in a single top level tag. So wrap the value using main tag / parent tag.

Example: `value={"<div>"+item+"</div>"}`

This is the other method I found.

use variable which stores regex `const regex = /<br|\n|\r\s*\\?>/g;`

Then use this regex in replace function

```
<HTMLView
  value={`<div>${symptom.text.trim().replace(regex, '')}</div>`}
  stylesheet={webViewStyle}
/>
```